# To extract Title from the_content

Tags: php, wordpress

I am getting Title of post inside Content. As code "the_content" including Title of content inside it. But I want to separate my Title from content. How this can be possible in php/wordpres.

Mine Current Code:

```
 <div class="content-holder"> 
   <?php the_content(); ?>                                                                          
      </div>
```

What should I want :

```
 <div class="content-holder">   
  <h1><?php the_title();?></h1>
  <hr style="margin-top: 20px;"/>                                                                         
    <?php the_content(); ?>  
</div>
```

As second code is generating Title Twice.

Comment: ...are you sure? As far as I was aware, `the_content` would exclude the title, do you have another title in the content section?

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure there is nothing in the content editor itself.
2. Find the template for the content , either content-page.php, content-single.php, content.php or similar and check those for duplicate the_title() function.
3. Inspect the title and assure they have the same classes  and try searching in your theme for one and the other.

Comment: Great troubleshooting tips! I was going crazy finding this bug until I searched for the classes that were placed on the title. With that I was able to track this issue down in no time.